# Run shiny app with rstudioserver on centos error "Connection Refused"

Tags: shiny, centos, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I have trouble with my shiny app run in my rstudio server on my centos Server.

When i run a shiny app in my rstudio-server IDE, a new browser windows open (that's normal) but i have this error "Connection Refused".

I run the "hello world" shiny app (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/example-01-hello.html) in my home directory.

I have also a shiny-server on this centos server for run my deploy application, and this work fine.

You can see my all soft version

- CentOS Stream release 8
- R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
- RStudio Server 2021.09.1 Build 372 2009-2021 RStudio, PBC "Ghost Orchid" Release (8b9ced18, 2021-11-08) for CentOS 8

-shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.18.987 (Node.js v16.14.0)

In my Rstudio IDE they are no message error, the applucation is running (with error message) and i have this

```
> runApp('test')

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7880
```

If I forgot something do not hesitate, thank you for your help.

Best Regards

Quentin B.

Comment: Hi,

We try on new VM Centos 8 stream without httpd and shiny-server, juste R 4.1 and rstudio-server and we have the same problem.

Do you think the problem could be from the R version and/or CentOS version ?

Comment: We are also running into same issue with centos 7, were you able to make any headway here?